# Executing Python cgi files in Apache on Windows

Tags: python, apache, cgi

I am trying to run a very simple "Hello World" program with Apache.
However, Apache returns a 500 Internal Server Error when it tries to execute my python file.
I've read several similar topics on here and tried the suggestions, no luck.
Things I have tried:

1. Including the AddHandler with .py files to the .conf file
2. Adding ExecCGI to the "Options Indexes" line in the .conf.
3. Making sure the first thing output is ""Content-Type:text/html" with **2** end of line characters.
4. Adding a shebang line to the top of the python file to direct to the Python interpreter. I'm not sure if I'm doing this part right.
5. Restarting Apache

The tools I am using include:

- Windows 7
- Python 3.5
- Apache 2.4

My code:
The HTML File (in the htdocs folder in the Apache folder):

```
<form action="/cgi-bin/hello_get.py" method="post">
First Name: <input type="text" name="first_name">  <br />

Last Name: <input type="text" name="last_name" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

The python file (in the cgi-bin folder):

```
# Note that I tried this without the C:/ also
#!C:/Users/MyName/workspace/Flask/flask/Scripts

# Import modules for CGI handling
import cgi, cgitb

# Create instance of FieldStorage
form = cgi.FieldStorage()

# Get data from fields
first_name = form.getvalue('first_name')
last_name  = form.getvalue('last_name')

print("Content-Type:text/html\r\n\r\n")
print("<html>")
print("<head>")
print("<title>Hello - Second CGI Program</title>")
print("</head>")
print("<body>")
print("<h2>Hello %s %s</h2>" % (first_name, last_name))
print("</body>")
print("</html>")
```

Comment: I know Flask but I am required to use Apache :/

Comment: then use `Apache+mod_wsgi` + `Gunicorn+Flask` (or maybe `Apache+mod_wsgi+Flask`)

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out.

In my shebang line, instead of:

```
#!C:/Users/MyName/workspace/Flask/flask/Scripts
```

I should have:

```
#!C:/Users/MyName/workspace/Flask/flask/Scripts/python.exe
```

I thought my shebang should have a path to where the python interpreter lives, I didn't realize I needed the actual full path of the interpreter.

It is working now.

So to recap, if you are having this issue after following these instructions:
http://editrocket.com/articles/python_apache_windows.html
Make sure that if you are using Windows the path is the full absolute path from the C:/ drive to the python.exe executable.